# Как сделать работу chrome расширения активной в фоновом режиме.(даже когда расширение закрыто)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

"manifest_version": 2,

У меня есть скрипт который обновляет данные каждые 10 сек, и взависимости от полученных данных у меня изменяеться цвет иконки расширения.

Хочу сделать такой функционал даже когда chrome расширение закрыто.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: -1 за слово "разширение".

Comment: Спасибо что не прошли мимо. P.S я не русскоговорящий

Comment: Расширения могут создавать WebWorker

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/#background-manifest